# How to create a translucent image-as-plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, workflow

I have imported an image as plane PNG in cycles render, with premultiplied alpha, emission and transparent. I would like to adjust its transparency.  How do I do this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you upload an image to make things a bit clearer?

Comment: Oh wait do you mean adjust how clear the image plane is?

Comment: I think I understand, what @WhishyQ is getting at is using the import image as plane add-on, and giving the the material the imported material some added transparency via cycles. This may be a challenge with a combination of mix/ transparent/ and diffuse shaders, but certainly can be done. Can you fill us in on the details of the object if it is anything beyond Blender's defaults? Pictures do help, even more so .blend files. They be uploaded to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for further inspection.

Comment: You would like to adjust it's transparency in the 3d viewport on screen or in the rendered output (aka clicking the render button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Converter/math node between the alpha and the mix shader of the node tree.

[image]

Changing the values between 0 to 1, you can determine how the alpha affects the transparency. 0 will be fully transparent, 1 will be opaque.

[image]